# Firebase Initialization (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a small little application with React so I can test out all of the cool features Firebase provides out of the box. However, I am confused as to why my initializer actually works. This may not even be firebase specific, but I figured it's close enough to ask here first.

So I was just messing around, and made a config file named ,"firebase-config.js", with the following code,

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
   apiKey: "dkd8dafdf8dfs8ds8fdsjf8dsfjsdf8jdfjdfs8",
   authDomain: "example.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
   storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "3232323232323"
};

var fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fb;
```

Inside of all my components that require the use of firebase commands, I have the following import statement, which is calling out the firebase npm module I have installed.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase
```

***Here's where things start to get a little bit fuzzy for me.***

The application doesn't run unless I include this import statement in the top of one of my components files,

```
import fb from '../../utils/firebase-config';
```

I can include this statement even in one of my components that isn't a parent component, and it still works. Does anyone have any clue what this is actually doing?

It may be helpful to clone the repo of it that I have, and run it locally to see what I am talking about.

https://github.com/DZuz14/firebaseauth

Here is a live working version of it on Heroku,
https://dzfirebaseauthsample.herokuapp.com/

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. If you don't import the file, your initialization code will not get executed.